# Best way to find max serial num in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a column named ID(VARCHAR 60)

The data of ID is linked by  id_num + serial num.

For example, a group data is below

- 367618648+0001
- 367618648+0002
- 51687687+0001
- 51687687+0002
- 51687687+0003
- 51687687+0004

I want to know  the best way to find the max "serial num" for an "id_num"?

Comment: Is `367618648+0001` all in the `id` field?

Comment: That's poor schema design. It should really be two separate columns.

Comment: Yes. I know the schema is bad  ,but this is a old database with large data and that's why i am asking how to solve this:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring_index()`.  The following gets the max for all `id_num`s:

```
select substring_index(id, '+', 1) as id_num,
       max(substring_index(id, '+', -1) + 0) as serial_num
from t
group by id_num;
```